# Keras neural net error with array - "please provide model targets either a single array or a list of arrays."

Tags: python, arrays, keras, neural-network

I'm pretty new to keras. When fitting my sequential model, I pass in an array of 1's and 0's as the y_train variable, 
and I get this error:

```
ValueError: Please provide as model targets either a single array or a
list of arrays.
```

You passed:

```
y=[1, 0, 1...0, 1, 1]
```

Note : the three dots just indicating the abbreviation of a very long array

It looks like a single array to me, so why isn't it working?

I did ctrl+f to look for brackets and didn't find any nested arrays, so I'm pretty much certain that it's a single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, realized I was trying to pass in a python array instead of a numpy array